# What is the fastest way to assign a variable in a class that implements Runnable?

Tags: java, android

I have a class A that has a class B object. Class B has a boolean variable bool that the A instance keeps updating (off events). The B object b implements Runnable.

```
class A{
  private B b;
}

class B implements Runnable{
  private boolean bool;

  run(){
    while(true){
      if(bool){//do something}
    }
  }
}
```

I assume that the boolean bool is actually on a’s thread because it is initialized when a calls B’s constructor, and the b thread does not begin until start is called on the b instance, and start is not called until after bool has been initialized.

If this is the case then the b thread must keep its own copy of bool. If this is the case, what is the fastest way of altering bool from a such that the b thread will see it; making bool volatile, or is there some way to assign directly to b’s copy?

Please forget about the loop, it is for GLES20. What I need to know is whether b has its copy of bool, and what is the fastest way for an event thread to continuously update a boolean on the GL thread.

Comment: I'm not sure a busy wait is a good idea.  Surely a semaphore would be better here.

Comment: you might wanna write something similar to observer pattern instead of the while loop. also take a look at `PropertyChangeEvent` event.

Answer (score 1):

If at some stage the reads from and writes to the variable can be on different threads, you need some form of synchronization. In this case, the most sensible options are:

- making `bool` volatile
- using [an `AtomicBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html)

However, depending on your use case, there might be a better way to achieve your goal by using appropriate concurrent objects (such as latches, semaphores or queues for example) and avoid the busy waiting which is going to use many CPU cycles unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Java's Exchanger seems to be what I need. It sets up an object between the threads rather than generating a new object every transaction and GCing it after the transaction.

There is a good explanation and code here:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/exchanger-and-gc-less-java.html